# Apple maps connecting beginning point with endpoint at swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

we are writing a code for navigation at swift. We implemented local database and downloaded our data into the app for offline navigation. But we have a problem. When we drawing road, its connecting beginning and endpoints

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     CizimVeriler();
}

func CizimVeriler(){
    var annotationCizim = getMapCizim()
      var polyline2 : MKPolyline = MKPolyline()
    var points: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
    for annotation in annotationCizim {
        points.append(annotation.coordinate)
    }
    polyline2 = MKPolyline(coordinates: &points, count: points.count)
    mapView.add(polyline2)
}


func getMapCizim() -> [Station] {
    var annotationCizim:Array = [Station]()
       annotationCizim.removeAll()
    var stationCizim: NSArray?
    do {
        let secim =  UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "RotaId") as! Int;
        let filtrele = try self.database.prepare(self.RotaKoordinatTable.where(RotaKoorId == secim))
        for rota in filtrele {
            let x1 = Double(rota[(self.KoorX)])
            let y1 = Double(rota[(self.KoorY)])
            let annotation = Station(latitude: y1!, longitude: x1!)
            annotation.title = "S1" as? String
            annotationCizim.append(annotation)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    return annotationCizim
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    if overlay is MKPolyline {
        let polyLineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: overlay as! MKPolyline)
        polyLineRenderer.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8961519599, green: 0.1830670238, blue: 0.06986772269, alpha: 1)
        polyLineRenderer.lineWidth = 1
        return polyLineRenderer
    }
    return MKOverlayRenderer()
}
```

[image: Problem]

Comment: Have a look on this https://www.iostutorialjunction.com/2018/03/draw-route-on-apple-map-or-mapkit-tutorial-in-swift4.html

Comment: One cannot tell where the start point and the end point are.

Comment: Evidently annotationCizim has one too many points. Delete the last point.

Comment: @ElTomato, that direct line should not be drawn. its start and endpoints are in fact my list's first and last points. It has routes for jogging and walking at outbacks